# sql question: How to count users by range of 30 days from a given date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**WHAT I'M STRUGGLING WITH:**

so I would like to count all distinct users ids from the (event_date -30) to event_date, I'm struggling to find how to group by a range of dates.

**WHAT I HAVE:**
The table below is what I have from a query that count my daily active users

```
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date), day) AS daily_date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT organization_id) as daily_active
FROM 
    `[app]-project.analytics_[numbers].events_intraday_*`,
    (SELECT value.string_value AS organization_id FROM (SELECT value FROM `[app]-project.analytics_[numbers].events_intraday_*`, UNNEST(user_properties) WHERE key = "organization_id") as user_properties_org) as value
WHERE
    (event_name = 'Active Seller Event')
GROUP BY
    daily_date
ORDER BY
    daily_date
```

| event_date | daily_active_count |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-08-06 | 5 |
| 2021-08-05 | 6 |
| 2021-08-04 | 7 |
| 2021-08-03 | 8 |
| 2021-08-02 | 9 |
| 2021-08-01 | 20 |
| 2021-07-30 | 9 |
| 2021-07-29 | 20 |

**What I'M LOOKING FOR:**

I'm looking to group these by a range where `event_date between event_date - 30 AND event_date`

The result would look like this

| event_date | count_date_range | active_30_days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-06 | 2020-07-24 to 2021-08-06 | 84 |
| 2021-08-05 | 2020-07-23 to 2021-08-05 | 79 |
| 2021-08-04 | 2020-07-22 to 2021-08-04 | 72 |
| 2021-08-03 | 2020-07-21 to 2021-08-03 | 64 |
| 2021-08-02 | 2020-07-20 to 2021-08-02 | 55 |
| 2021-08-01 | 2020-07-19 to 2021-08-01 | 35 |
| 2021-07-30 | 2020-07-18 to 2021-07-30 | 26 |
| 2021-07-29 | 2020-07-17 to 2021-07-29 | 20 |

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the dates you want and then use `left join` and aggregation.  You haven't shown examples of your data and your query is rather arcane, but I think this is the logic:

```
SELECT dte, COUNT(DISTINCT orgnaization_id) as daily_active,
    DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date), day) AS daily_date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT organization_id) as daily_active
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE '2021-07-29', DATE '2021-08-06', INTERVAL 1 DAY) dte LEFT JOIN
     (`[app]-project.analytics_[numbers].events_intraday_*` e JOIN 
      UNNEST(e.user_properties) kv
      ON kv.key = 'organization_id' AND
         e.event_name = 'Active Seller Event'
     ) 
     ON dte = PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date)
GROUP BY dte
ORDER BY dte;
```

I don't understand why you would be storing `event_date` as a string.  Nor why your version of the query is doing a `CROSS JOIN` of the table to itself.